# Unicode (Devanagari) characters not showing up correctly in HTML dropdown and text-field tags

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, textfield, unicode-string

I have a HTML page in which I need to show a dropdown containing Devanagari characters.

The problem I am facing is that in the DOM the characters show up in expected manner but in the browser it doesn't. And the same problem is with displaying those characters in text-field tag (i.e. `input type=text`) but in `div` elements the characters shows up correctly. Please refer the snippet below reproducing the issue.

**Note**: In my original page I am using "Mustard UI" as CSS framework thus I have included its CDN in my snippet just to ensure that the problem I am facing is not related to fonts-issue.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mustard-ui@latest/dist/css/mustard-ui.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      In Dropdown
      <select name="my-dropdown" class="my-dropdown">
        <option value="1">श्री गणेश</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div>
      Inside DIV: श्री गणेश
    </div>

    <div>
      In Text-field 
      <input type='text' value='श्री गणेश'>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody please explain what is the problem and how to fix it? I don't think this is a font issue because as said the characters appear correctly in DOM and also making those characters display in a `div` they appear in expected manner.

Following is the information of the browsers I have and in both of them I am facing the issue explained:

Mozilla Firefox 113.0.2 (64-bit), Google Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for pointing to resources highlighting the problems with attaching screenshots and why I should replace them with snippets. I have take the necessary actions and now I hope that community should be able to help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Your linked stylesheet does not specify fonts, so browser is falling back to system fonts. By default it falls back to the system font for caption for the dropdown and input field. Obviously the caption font fallback on your system is to a font that does not adequately support the language of the text. It is using a separate fallback for for the contents of the `div`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [@Andj's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900137/unicode-devanagari-characters-not-showing-up-correctly-in-html-dropdown-and-te?noredirect=1#comment136476619_76900137) adding the font CSS and applying the style, using the font, to select and input fields finally it works as expected. Please refer a working snippet below (the snippet is based on the one I have used in my question)

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/mustard-ui@latest/dist/css/mustard-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+Devanagari">

  <style>
    .my-dropdown {
      font-family: 'Noto Sans Devanagari', serif;
    }
    
    .my-text-input {
      font-family: 'Noto Sans Devanagari', serif;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    In Dropdown
    <select name="my-dropdown" class="my-dropdown">
      <option value="1">श्री गणेश</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    Inside DIV: श्री गणेश
  </div>

  <div>
    In Text-field
    <input type='text' value='श्री गणेश' class='my-text-input'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.